# Vagrant + Docker + Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ftp, docker, vagrant

I installed vagrant on a Mac and I want to achieve this :

1. Launch vagrant up and have a vagrant with docker installed and docker compose
2. Install Wordpress with mysql inside this vagrant machine with docker-compose up
3. Have the folder (/var/www/html) of the docker container mapped as volume in my vagrant machine at /dockermapinVagrant
4. Have this /dockermapinVagrant onto my host(OS X) and be able to modify files directly from the host

I achieved that and everything works perfectly.
I can add templates from my OS X host with no problems (dragging the theme in the themes folder on my host OS X), see the changes directly of the Wordpress site using my browser ...

**The problem**

- I noticed is that I can not install any plugins on Wordpress (
  dashboard -> updates ) I have a message :

  - To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not
    remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.

**Solution i tried**

Change the permission in the docker container wp by setting the user to www-data and chmod to 777 but on some folder as wp-content it doesn’t change to 777. Moreover setting the owner to www-data doesn’t work at all it stay always to 1000:1000 in the container.

**Is there a way to update the plugins on wordpress in a docker container without FTP ?**

Is there maybe a better way do to that ? Use a data-only container on the vagrant machine with FTP access to the mounted volume ? And map the data container volume on the vagrant machine then to the host to have direct access and see changes directly during the dev process. But I do not want to give FTP access directly on the data-only container (FTP is not secure and I prefer to manage the backup and the data from the vagrant machine directly and delete the mapped volumes in production)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can achieve this, and it's probably just the missing line

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

in your `wp-config` file. You should setup each WordPress outside of the docker environment first IMHO; and then import the database, and WordPress files etc into docker using your `Dockerfile`(s) as part of staging and deployment, which should be distinct from development (although some of deployment will be shared).

On better ways of managing, I would not put docker inside vagrant if at all possible; it adds unnecessary complexity to that stage of development. I would use vagrant exclusively, focus on getting my provisioning scripts ready (as I use scripts between vagrant and docker), and work via SFTP directly to the vagrant box; committing changes via git. You can then focus your efforts on the necessary code and pull what you need when you need to.

Once it gets to the stage of testing, or staging, I use the provisioner scripts to help me build my docker environment consistently, (probably sharing some of the provisioning code). I Can then pull a specific release from my repo, and build it into my docker image, which I can deploy.

Other alternatives if you really want spin up, delete WordPress, get to grips with the [WP-CLI command-line tools](http://wp-cli.org/), which can install WordPress, plugins, manage updates and install integrity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Can you explain more about the : I would use vagrant exclusively, focus on getting my provisioning scripts ready (as I use scripts between vagrant and docker), and work via SFTP directly to the vagrant box; committing changes via git. More precisely committing change about what ? the changes in which code ? my provisioning scripts ready (as I use scripts between vagrant and docker) What kind of scripts ?

Comment: So Personally, I would git init inside each plugin and theme folder that I was planning to edit., or git clone them if they were already under source control. I would do this via SSH (anything with SFTP should also support SSH, and under linux and Mac, hosts I believe vagrant ssh, will connect for you).

As for committing changes, you would use SSH and git commit in order to stage changes inside the vagrant, as well as other git tags to ensure that you are never uploading files (git commit -am them instead)

Comment: Also the scripts I use are regular shell scripts, but occasionally if a naughty coder forgets what they have done, I have been known to comb through bash history files for what they have done (never makes me happy,but it works)

Comment: Thanks you for the answer i will apply this method too now !

Comment: Update: I no longer bake code into a docker image. I do read only mount the folder with the code, which means a non-public docker with R/W access is the only way to modify files. As much as I accept this might be a headache for a certain type of developer or team. It forces me to think in an event driven or queued architecture leading to faster request->response (although not necessarily faster desired result, it does really speed up WP or any development).